# 'Find all references' not working in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, find-all-references

I was able to do 'Find all reference' a couple of hours ago, and now suddenly it stopped working. When I do 'Find all references', its always says 'Search found 0 references'. I have reinstalled visual studio but the problem still exists.

Anyone has any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: you might get it if you rebuild the solution.

Comment: @cornerback84 Please let us know if something worked for you on this issue. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: well, one of my fellow had the same problem. He followed what 'wallyk' posted and he also removed the .ncb files of all projects. It started working for him, but mine is still not working (I have tried both steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `.ilk`, `.pch`, and `.pdb` files in the Debug or Release subdirectory.  Then do `build all`.  It should reconstitute and work after that, especially after reinstalling VS.

Comment: I would like to add that deleting .ncp file also helps

Answer (score 1):

Find all references generally only works when you have the project loaded. If you load a source file independently, it doesn't work. This also does not work across compiled libraries. Basically, if visual studio cannot resolve the reference using the source tree currently loaded, it will not work.

Comment: No, its not a single file. Its a complete project. I am able to do 'Find all references' for other projects but not this particular big project that I am working on. I have deleted the .ncb file, but it still won't work

Comment: @Chris I have a project with multiple compiled libraries within it. Your answer seems to imply that "find all references" will not work properly for me. Is that true? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to find the "Find Symbol Results" windows (Ctrl-Alt-F12), its probably floating somewhere out of your windows (mine was near the status bar :)).

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old thread as I am using VS2017 on Windows 7 but the same problem occurred to me.
My solution was to close VS and locate a folder called ".vs" in your solution folder structure. Note: you may need to turn off hide system folders in order to see it.

Delete this folder and re-open VS and your project. I believe this causes a database rebuild and fixed my issue.

Mark